# Process Start Did Not Work

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a windows service which is writing in C#.

When I start debug the program it is working without any problem. But if I publish it does not work and I am not getting any error in my log file or eventviwer.

I checked the UAC to never notify.

Also my code is like this:

```
using (Process tvProcess = new Process())
{
   tvProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = installationPath;
   tvProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
   tvProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
   tvProcess.StartInfo.FileName = TVAppFileName;

   bool started = tvProcess.Start();
   tvProcess.WaitForInputIdle();
   Logger.TraceFormat("TV - TV was started from the path {0}. Status : {1}",     
       System.IO.Path.Combine(installationPath, TVAppFileName), 
       started);
}
```

Also my installationPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version8\"
TVAppFileName = "TeamViewer.exe"
How can I start this process without debug?

Thanks

Comment: How is the external application added to your project? When you look to the installation directory is it there?

Comment: I get the installation path correctly. InstallationPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version8\"
TVAppFileName = "TeamViewer.exe"

Comment: what happens if you run your program as administrator

Comment: "`I have a windows service which is writing in C#.`" Does this mean that the above code is being run as a service? If it does, why are you attempting to start the TeamViewer client from inside a service? Please explain what your end goal is, you have fallen in to a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), by explaining what you are trying to accomplish we can help you reach it.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is likely that services can't really do anything interactive like starting up apps for the user to interact with...

Comment: I tried to start teamviwer via windows service

Comment: Might be a stupid question - but is there a reason you can't just use the windows task scheduler to do that?

Comment: @John Oh, I didn't notice this. If it's run as a service then 90% cases are permissions. Try to put your username and password in the service "run as" fields to verify.